# Multiple where clause with include ActiveRecord Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have two tables "patients" and "patient_funds"

```
patient:
id   status
1    active
2    active
3    inactive

patient_funds:
id    required    allocated   patient_id
1     10             5            1
2     10             10           2
```

I want to select 'active' patients having `required` = `allocated` from "patient_funds". i,e I want "patient_funds" with id 2 to be selected. How can I do it using `include`.

I tried something like

```
Patient.includes(:patient_funds).where(status: "active")
```

I want to add another condition on "patient_funds" table as I explained.
Something like

```
required LIKE allocated
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `includes` it just pulls data alongside your request to prevent N+1 query.

What you need is [join](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins)

```
Patient.joins(:patient_funds).where("patients.status = 'active' AND patient_funds.allocated > ?", 6)
# for example
```

This will get all `patients` that have `patient_funds` and `allocated` > 6